# How to Set variables inside a Linux for loop

Tags: bash

I'm trying to determine the existing HDDs in each system using a for loop as show below, the problem is when I try to set the variable using the below code i get sda=true: command not found. What is the proper way to do this?

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in a b c d e f
do
    grep -q sd$i /proc/partitions
    if [ $? == 0 ]
    then
        sd$i=true
    else
        sd$i=false
    fi
done
```

Comment: `declare sd$i=true`
So there is one catch I have found with this. When I use this in a function, the variable is null outside of the function. How do I get around this?

Comment: you would use `export` in this case. (I have updated my answer.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use an array or `declare`:

```
declare sd$i=true
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use an array in this case. For example:

```
$ i=a
$ sd[$i]=true
$ echo ${sd[a]}
true
```

As another poster stated, if you want to do this without an array, you can instead make a local variable by using syntax like `declare sd$i=true`. If you want to make a global variable, use `export sd$i=true`.

Comment: Unless you're using Bash 4 and associative arrays (`declare -A sd`), the index will resolve to 0 (unless `a` is a variable that ultimately resolves to a number). `for i in {a..f}; do unset $i; sd[i]=true; done; declare -p sd` will result in "`declare -a sd='([0]="true")'`" (only one element).

Comment: @Dennis, thanks for the heads up. (I was testing with bash 4.1.5.)

Answer (score 0):

[BASH FAQ entry #6: "How can I use variable variables (indirect variables, pointers, references) or associative arrays?": "Assigning indirect/reference variables"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Assigning_indirect.2BAC8-reference_variables)